# How small may I design objects for the Prusa i3 MK3?

Tags: prusa-i3, resolution

I have designed a bread mark and printed it on the Prusa i3 MK3.

[image: Bread mark]

I wanted it to have as sharp edges as possible, so I used a triangle:

[image: Triangle]

However, it seems that the print cut off layers that are too thin (x-y-wise) and instead of a 1 cm high bread mark, I only have 0.5 cm.

What is the X-Y-resolution of the Prusa i3 MK3? In Slic3r, can I make sure that any wall is made as thick as needed for it to be printed?

I have the default 0.4 mm nozzle.

Comment: What is the size of your nozzle? From my understanding, you can only print that wide at a minimum. Also, if you print it as thin as you can get to, won't the top be so thin it wouldn't be very resilient? I'd think you'd need to make the profile trapezoidal versus triangular, then set the top to the size of nozzle you're using. I'm no expert, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on the slicer and the nozzle diameter. Typically, you cannot print a wall smaller than twice the nozzle diameter because walls need an inner and outer line. Therefore, your slicer will make some cutoff and won't print walls below a certain threshold, in order to try to faithfully replicate your model.

Slic3r, I believe, will automatically go down to single line walls, but if you turn on "Detect thin walls" in Slic3r's Print Settings, more of the thin walls will be printed. Slic3r will actually reduce the plastic extruded to attempt to make even thinner walls, but there's still a limit.

With a 0.4 mm nozzle, you should design walls no smaller than 0.8 mm, or 0.4 mm at the very smallest.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute minimum a slicer will allow existing in a g-code is one extrusion diameter, which is typically roundabout a nozzle diameter. So for a standard 0.4 mm nozzle, the model will be cut in a way that keeps at *least* 0.4 mm thick walls, or, if the slicer is extra careful, double that, as the model demands 2 walls next to each other. The result is, that the model with such sharp walls will be cut till the model does conform to the minimum wall thickness - in your case about half the height of the model.

I strongly encourage to further read [What special considerations must be taken when designing parts for 3D printing?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6830/8884)