# What slicers have support for belt printers, or could have support added via a plugin?

Tags: slicing, belt-printer

What slicers have support for belt printers like the CR-30?  Or what slicers can have an add-on, plugin, or extension added to them to support it (from a user level, not a dev level).

I found more total slicers than I expected, since I was only expecting 3 (Cura, PrusaSlicer, Simplify3d).  Surely that means I'm missing out on more, if there are already so many different slicers.

- Creality Slicer - Comes from the OEM of the printer
- Blackbelt Cura - Everyone who mentions it says don't use it because it's old
- Raise3d Ideamaker - Seems to be based on Flashforge's slicer, has some interesting features too.  Not as configurable as Slic3r or PrusaSlicer though.

Comment: [Somewhat Related](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/14923/what-effects-does-the-non-carthesian-coordinate-system-have-on-the-part-design-p) due to the explanation of the odd coordinate system in the Opener.

Answer (score 2):

It seems **Creality** provides a modified version of **Cura 4.8.2** for the **CR30**: [Creality Download](https://www.creality.com/pages/download-cr-30-3d-printer) ; **BlackBelt** does the same, another modified version of Cura 3.6.2: [Blackbelt Download](https://blackbelt-3d.com/download-area/).

The current version of **Cura** (5.x) does not limit the area in size, but it seems very difficult to use it like that for belt printers (eg printing the same object many times), so you have to use a dedicated slicer.

Some possible tricks: printing the same object many times could require a simple edit/processing of the gcode, plz ask for this because it's another question.

Comment: @Trish: thank you for editing with more accurate infos.

Answer (score -1):

I think most slicers don't distinguish printers based on if they have belts or delta configuration, etc.  The slicer generates gcode, and the firmware on the printer translates the gcode into actuator motions specific to that printer to perform the gcode.

The difference slicers generally care about is if it is a FFF printer that extrudes a bead or a resin printer that solidifies liquid.   Many other 3d printing methods exist, but those to are the most common ones supported by most of the open slicers.

Comment: Modern belt printers are all at weird angles (15, 30, 45, etc) for the belt, necessitating special slicer support.