# Source of design advice for modeling functional parts

Tags: 3d-design

Where do I go for deeper knowledge about 3D printing functional parts?

I want to up my game a bit and design some more functional parts. In particular, I want to do more with boxes, organizers, and moving systems.

For instance, I've found some [YouTube videos showing hinge design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSBsBTMsGTk), but I want more. I want more details on WHY they chose the pin to be 1.5 mm diameter, etc.  I want design options (can the hinge be somewhere other than halfway between top and bottom).

I'd also like to know how to do enclosures that snap together (same problem: YouTube shows me one or two designs, not much detail on why they are designed that way or how to change them if they snap off).

I want box tops that can stay on. How do I make clasps? Sliding lids? Hinges with stops? Snaps?

I haven't even started to mention my desires to learn about levers/gears/etc.

Can anyone recommend a good book? Or a course? Or a really good YouTuber?

Comment: This is *incredible* wide. You should read [special considerations for 3D printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6726/what-special-considerations-must-be-taken-when-designing-parts-for-3d-printing)

Comment: @Trish, thanks for the pointer.  But, I'm not looking for that kind of advice.  I understand the 3D printing process pretty well, and can design parts with the right overhang or bridging factors, for instance.  What I'm searching for is design advice for how to model the actual parts.

Comment: Then this is a recommendation question, which is disallowed on the stack unless extremely specific. You are looking for an engineering and/or product design class/book at that scale. You can ask about *specific* problems, but for that Engineering SE might be the even better choice.