# Can you recommend professional 3D metal printing books?

Tags: metal-printing, literature

I am a fresh graduate student in 3D metal printing. My undergraduate major is mechanical engineering. Later research will focus on the process of metal 3D printing. I hope that you can recommend some excellent 3D metal printing books for learning.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [3d printing references for beginner](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/3d-printing-references-for-beginner), but that isn't specifically metal

Comment: Don't requests for resources go to Meta?

Comment: Google throws up three: [3D Printing with Metals for Design Engineers, Explained](https://www.designnews.com/materials-assembly/free-e-book-3d-printing-metals-design-engineers-explained/200976711359482), [Additive Manufacturing of Metals: The Technology, Materials, Design and Production](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319551272), [Additive Manufacturing of Metals: From Fundamental Technology to Rocket Nozzles, Medical Implants, and Custom Jewelry (Springer Series in Materials Science)](https://www.amazon.com/Additive-Manufacturing-Metals-Fundamental-Technology/dp/3319582046)

Comment: This is free [3D Printing of metals](https://www.mdpi.com/books/pdfview/book/384)

Comment: @Davo - Not sure, where did you read that? Is there an SE.Meta link?

Comment: @Greenonline I'm probably remembering this from this [Meta.ELU Q&A](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11609/where-does-it-say-that-resources-are-off-topic-on-main), and that I believed it to be a site-wide policy. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

This is a free ebook that I have perused briefly which it looks interesting, and it is free (did I say that already?)

- [3D Printing of metals](https://www.mdpi.com/books/pdfview/book/384)

  - Manoj Gupta
  - ISBN 978-3-03842-591-5 (Pbk);
  - ISBN 978-3-03842-592-2 (PDF)

Three other books that *might* be of interest are:

- [3D Printing with Metals for Design Engineers, Explained](https://www.designnews.com/materials-assembly/free-e-book-3d-printing-metals-design-engineers-explained/200976711359482)

  - Ann R. Thryft
  - Downloadable free ebook, but some sort of sign up is required
- [Additive Manufacturing of Metals: The Technology, Materials, Design and Production](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319551272),

  - Yang, L., Hsu, K., Baughman, B., Godfrey, D., Medina, F., Menon, M., Wiener, S.
  - ISBN 978-3-319-55128-9
- [Additive Manufacturing of Metals: From Fundamental Technology to Rocket Nozzles, Medical Implants, and Custom Jewelry (Springer Series in Materials Science)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319582046)

  - Although, as the title contains a (rather obvious) mis-spelling, it does not bode well for the rest of the book.
  - John O. Milewski
  - ISBN-13: 978-3319582047
  - ISBN-10: 3319582046

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that ultimately you get a lot more quick practical knowledge from your machine's manufacturer or DMLS service provider so don't forget to look at publications from the industry leaders.  They have incentive to make sure you succeed when using their products.  Just beware the salesmanship.

For example Stratasys:
https://www.stratasysdirect.com/resources/design-guidelines/direct-metal-laser-sintering

I believe there's also a very similar guide from Xometry and others.  Gpi also had some good insights on some of the more exotic materials.